google bots replace/update the rows inserted than add value/data in news rows. doing when hight traffic request data
hellow guys, i have some problem here.
I have an application that uses Google Sheet API requests for around 200 requests per second into 1 sheet. I use 5 service account credentials to work on 1 sheet. I have problems with my Google Sheet account service.
so when (number 1 service account) has entered data into the range/rows. than another like (google service account 4) actually updates/changes the data into the range that has been filled in.
instead of adding a new row after the data is filled in. This happens when write requests occur very quickly.
How do I prevent the bot/Google service account from making changes/updates after the range/rows are filled in, but it will always add a new row after the row/range is filled in?
this just do when hight traffic request, when low traffic apps run perfectly
this is example the problemexample image
